# UTILS.JS issue and "Mailto:" link issue with google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am working on one website and we have UTILS.JS which makes page opacity 0 before loading. My issue is that I have a link for "mailto:" but for some reason when Email window opens the page add that css of opacity 0 to whole page on Google Chrome only. Does any one had this kind of issue?

Is there any alternative for "mailto:" if this is problem by Google Chrome only?
** I can remove that line of code where it adds the opacity but I am not sure why the ex developer added in first place, so if there is solution without changing script will be really helpful.

```
<a class="zuc-btn zuc-btn-secondary" href="mailto:resumes@zucora.com">Apply Now</a>
```

```
$('html').css('opacity', 0);
$(document).on('click', '.LTAddToCart', function () {
    var Btn = $(this);
    LT.Cart.AddItem(
        Btn.attr('data-lt-item-id'),
        Btn.attr('data-lt-quantity') || 1,
        Btn.attr('data-lt-item-type-id')
    );
});
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $('html').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 60);
};
```